# Не получается получить нужную часть сайта в Python 3, используя BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Изучаю Python и для получения опыта решил "пограбить" разные сайты.

Наткнулся на http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!= 
и пытаюсь с него стянуть часть выделенную звездами (`**`), она отвечает за список городов в выпадающем меню.

```
<div id="cinema-city-selector" class="dropdown dropdown-tip dropdown-anchor-right">
    <div class="dropdown-panel">
    **<div class="city-caption">**
```

Когда стягиваю, получаю результат в виде

```
[<div class="city-caption">
        Днепропетровск</div>, <div class="city-caption">
        Житомир</div>, <div class="city-caption">
        Запорожье</div>, <div class="city-caption">
        Ивано-Франковск</div>,
```

и т. д., но **без** ссылок, хотя в dev-панели хрома ссылки видны.

Соответственно **вопрос: как стянуть эту часть, чтоб она была со ссылками?**

<sub>P.S. Grab эту часть вообще не увидел. Я так понял это из-за JavaScript. (Ну или я еще просто нуб и не заставил его увидеть эту часть). В любом случае, как для нуба BeautifulSoup мне показался понятнее.</sub>

<sub>P.P.S. Как альтернатива, можно с другой части сайта брать города в транслите, загонять в цикл подставляя под нужный шаблон-адрес, и делать ссылки на города самому, но хотелось бы решить/понять данную проблему, а не искать обходной путь.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметьте для начала, что элемент ссылки не входит в `div`, который вы собираете:

```html
<li class="cinema-city">
    <div class="city-caption">
        Днепропетровск</div>
        <ul class="cinemas-list">
                <li class="cinema" data-alias="kinoodessa-kinostancia">
            <a href="/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia">Одессакино Киностанция</a></li>
                <li class="cinema" data-alias="mx-dnepr-karavan">
            <a href="/cinema/mx-dnepr-karavan">Мультиплекс в ТРЦ «Караван»</a></li>
                </ul>

</li>
```

Вы можете вывести результат работы метода `prettify()` объекта `BeautifulSoup`, и это станет заметно:

```html
<li class="cinema-city">
 <div class="city-caption">
  Днепропетровск
 </div>
 <ul class="cinemas-list">
  <li class="cinema" data-alias="kinoodessa-kinostancia">
   <a href="/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia">
    Одессакино Киностанция
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="cinema" data-alias="mx-dnepr-karavan">
   <a href="/cinema/mx-dnepr-karavan">
    Мультиплекс в ТРЦ «Караван»
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Соответственно, для получения ссылок стоит извлекать объекты с классом `cinema-city`, например, так:

```
soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'cinema-city'})
```

и дальше из них уже добывать всё, что требуется.

---

**Дополнение**

Выяснилось, что вид отображаемой страницы по этому адресу зависит от выставленных cookie. Для того, чтобы можно было увидеть список городов с адресами, нужно задать cookie['city'] = 'zhitomir' (можно и другой город при желании, это не влияет) при запросе к странице.

Обычно, для работы с интернет-страницами, я использую библиотеку `requests`, она предоставляет удобный интерфейс и позволяет опустить множество деталей.

В ней скачать требуемую страницу можно следующим образом:

```
response = requests.get('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!=', 
                        cookies={'city': 'zhitomir'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode())
result = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'city-caption'})
```

В результате будет получен уже искомый список со ссылками, который можно обрабатывать дальше:

```
[<div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=dnepropetrovsk">Днепропетровск</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=zhitomir">Житомир</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=zaporozhe">Запорожье</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=ivano-frankovsk">Ивано-Франковск</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=kiev">Киев</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=kolomyya">Коломыя</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=krivojrog">Кривой Рог</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=lutsk">Луцк</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=lvov">Львов</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=mariupol">Мариуполь</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=nikolaev">Николаев</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=odessa">Одесса</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=rovno">Ровно</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=ternopol">Тернополь</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=kharkov">Харьков</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=kherson">Херсон</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=khmelnickij">Хмельницкий</a>
 </div>, <div class="city-caption">
 <a href="/cinema/?city=cherkassy">Черкассы</a>
 </div>]
```

Comment: Эм... Мы кажется в разные места сайта смотрим. Как я понял, вы обратили внимание на перечень кинотеатров в выбранном городе. С этим я справился.
Мне же нужны ссылки из выпадающего меню (где выбирается город). Строка "Кинотеатры в городе <нужный город>"

Comment: Хм, исходная ссылка приводила в другое место, видимо, идёт работа с сессией

Comment: Чтоб наверняка говорили об одном и том же - заходим по ссылке http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/#!= и переходим в "Кинотеатры" и сразу под этой кнопкой видим выпадающий список (с синим названием Города). Вот в Хроме в dev-панели я ссылки вижу из этого выпадающего списка, а в супе не вижу :)

Comment: Попробуйте сбросить cookie, и вы увидите, что в первый раз по этой ссылке выдаётся другая страница. Собственно её и получает BeautifulSoup. Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Сейчас должно работать так, как требуется.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понятно, почему оно тупило. К кукисам нужно было обратиться, а я не додумался... Все в лоб хотел.